# ASP.NET authentication forms not working with CSS?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, forms-authentication

So on my journey to become better at ASP.NET I've encountered a problem.

I'm working on a login. I added some style to it by adding a CSS file and after some time I made it look a lot better. Thereafter I added ASP authentication forms - which actually works great as well except that if you're not logged in the CSS is not used.

Once I've logged in and received a cookie I can go back to the login page and everything looks nice. But as long as I haven't "logged in" the page looks as if no CSS is used.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to allow access to the CSS file:

```
<location path="~/stylesheets">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Update to match the path to where you store your CSS.

Comment: Awesome this works like a charm. May I ask why location has to be before system.web? and why it's wrapped around most of the other things in the web.config file? and if I may sidetrack my own question what does allow users="*" exactly do? So far I've only written  <deny users="?" /> in my Authorization tag :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to exclude the CSS folder (and for that matter any other folders) from the authorization using location in the web.config.

```
<location path="CssFolder">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your CSS folder out of the protected area - put it under your root, and it should work.

The CSS for the protected files can reside in the (non-protected) anonymous access, root folder. The CSS for your protected files does not have to be in a protected folder, but if you must do that, then amit_g's solution should work for that scenario :)

Comment: What do you exactly mean by that?

Comment: The CSS for the protected files can reside in the (non-protected) anonymous access, root folder. The CSS for your protected files does not have to be in a protected folder, but if you must do that, then amit_g's solution should work for that scenario:)